# Django Models save() works on localhost, but not on a remote server

Tags: django, django-models

I'm working on a very basic Django app in hopes of teaching myself the framework, and I've hit a small snag. The app is intended to take user input, store it in a mysqlite database, and display the contents of the database on receiving a request. I have everything working properly when the app is run locally (manage.py runserver), however it's misbehaving once it's deployed. For some reason, the storage logic is malfunctioning on the live site (Windows Server 2012 via MS Azure).

Here is the code in question:

```
from django.http import HttpResponse
from django.shortcuts import render
from django.shortcuts import render_to_response
from helloworld.models import Registry

def home(request):
    return render_to_response("home.html")

def register(request):
    return render_to_response("register.html")

def view(request):
    entries = Registry.objects.all()
    args = {}
    args["entries"] = entries
    return render_to_response("registry.html", args)

def submit(request):
    nameIn = request.GET.get('name')
    ageIn = request.GET.get('age')
    monthIn = request.GET.get('month')
    try:
        Registry(name=nameIn, age=ageIn, month=monthIn).save()
    except:
        pass
    return view(request)
```

I've done a fair amount of debugging, and tried several approaches to storing the data. I've checked that the method is receiving valid values. I can't, for the life of me, figure out why that call to save() is throwing an error. Hopefully it will be obvious to one of you Django-pros! THanks in advance, any help will be greatly appreciated! P.s. I'm attaching my settings file, as i have a sneaking suspicion that poor configuration is the source of my troubles.

```
"""
Django settings for cny_solar project.

For more information on this file, see
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/topics/settings/

For the full list of settings and their values, see
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/ref/settings/
"""

# Build paths inside the project like this: os.path.join(BASE_DIR, ...)
import os
BASE_DIR = os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(__file__))


# Quick-start development settings - unsuitable for production
# See https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/howto/deployment/checklist/

# SECURITY WARNING: keep the secret key used in production secret!
SECRET_KEY = 's7xv#m=5h=mjrdg_7-$=7kr8kx4np9$@6qzlg+m4xt&6-@-zi2'

# SECURITY WARNING: don't run with debug turned on in production!
DEBUG = True

TEMPLATE_DEBUG = True

ALLOWED_HOSTS=['127.0.0.1','localhost']


# Application definition

INSTALLED_APPS = (
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    'helloworld',
)

MIDDLEWARE_CLASSES = (
    'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.SessionAuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',
)

ROOT_URLCONF = 'helloworld.urls'

WSGI_APPLICATION = 'helloworld.wsgi.application'


TEMPLATE_DIRS = (
    os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'templates'),
)

# Database
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/ref/settings/#databases

DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.sqlite3',
        'NAME': os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'db.sqlite3'),
    }
}

# Internationalization
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/topics/i18n/

LANGUAGE_CODE = 'en-us'

TIME_ZONE = 'UTC'

USE_I18N = True

USE_L10N = True

USE_TZ = True


# Static files (CSS, JavaScript, Images)
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/howto/static-files/

STATIC_ROOT = BASE_DIR

STATIC_URL = '/static/'

STATICFILES_DIRS = (
    ('assets', os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static')),
)
```

Comment: What error do you get?

Comment: May i suggest to use [forms](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/topics/forms/)?

Comment: Is any data at all being saved? Does the user running Django have write access to the directory sqlite is in? Also, as mentioned above, you should use Django forms (and at least validate/sanitize the data you're saving...)

Comment: And please, please, please remove that `except: pass`. You're catching *and silencing* every error that could occur, so of course you're not able to debug it. Only catch the errors you know you can deal with, and even then at least log them.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions! @Rohan I'm getting a 500 error from the server.

Comment: @Doc You certainly may, I'll take a look at the documentation.

Comment: @mevius At first I was sure that the app was running with sufficient permissions, but now I'm beginning to question that assumption. I'm using "ISS with FastCGI support" as described [here](http://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/virtual-machines-python-django-web-app-windows-server/). Not sure if that could be causing issues...